# How can I put a maximum check number in a checkbox with HTML?

Tags: html, forms, checkbox

I want to make a form (type checkbox), which it can select at least one option, adn at most two options, but I don't know how to code it in HTML...

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery for that, can be easily done using change event:

```
var limit = 1;
$('input.yourclassname').on('change', function(evt) {
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
   }
});
```

Comment: You can also add an `alert('Only one option can be selected');` after `this.checked=false;`